# How to fix basic for loop? Python

Tags: python, loops

I am having problems with a for loop. I have a list consensusSize which contains a range of random numbers. I only want to print if the number is greater than 50 and less than 200. Instead it is outputting all of them- want am I doing wrong?

```
for i in range(0, len(consensusSize)):
...     if consensusSize[i]>50 or consensusSize[i]<200:
...             print(consensusSize[i])
```

Comment: It's already in your own writing: _I only want to print if the number is greater than 50 **and** less than 200_. Compare this with your conditional.

Comment: Use and instead of or

Answer (score 4):

You should think of the python for-loop as a for-each loop:

```py
for i in consensusSize:
    if 50 < i < 200:
        print(i)
```

This would simplify your solution.

Comment: Clean solution. It will make the job.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `and`:

```
if consensusSize[i]>50 and consensusSize[i]<200:
```

Comment: but then it prints nothing. There is definitely items in the list that fulfill the rule. e.g. 178,7,63

Comment: What is the value of consensusSize? I just tried it on the console and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use "and" in line 2 instead of "or".

```
if consensusSize[i]>50 and consensusSize[i]<200:
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
x_list=[10,20,30]
y_list=[12,10,23]
for x,y in zip(x_list,y_list):
    print(x,y)
```

Comment: Providing code is good but you should provide some explanation too why your code works and what mistakes(if any) the person asking questions was making. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23592204)